# How to give CornerRadius to UIViewController Object iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cornerradius

can't i give the cornerRadius to UIViewController Object.

Comment: Why can't you but there is one slight change. You give the corner Radius for a UIView object and not a UIViewController object. I think you meant your viewcontroller's view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cornerRadius` is a property of a CALayer, which is associated with a UIView. A view controller can't have one, but it's `view` property can have:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

At the top of your view controller's .m file

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

You will probably also want to set the `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties of the layer, if you are looking for a visible rounded rect border, or `masksToBounds` if you just want to round off the corners.

Answer (score 5):

try this:-

```
CALayer *l = [*yourcontrolobject* layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Make sure you import `quartzCore framework` and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your `view controller.h` file